# Allow users to provide custom domains

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a next.js app on Now and I'm adding the ability for users to point domains at their account.  Kinda like about.me.

What's the best way to approach this?  I've done this in Rails in the past but not sure how to do it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to do the following:

1. Use the [ZEIT API](http://api.zeit.co/) to programmatically add domains.
2. If you are going for over 50 domains, make sure you know the limits of your account. Having too many domains will require an enterprise plan. Take a look at [this documentation](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/platform/limits).
3. If you are launching a business, a good support plan will help you get started with the API quickly. Again, take a look at Enterprising offerings if possible.
4. Reach out to support@zeit.co for any needed information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes it's a business - is this something that Cloudflare could handle on top Zeit Now?